# Should I still support Safari 4.0.4 on iOS 3.2 for my web app?

Tags: html, ios, css, ipad, safari

I just checked my web app in a first-generation iPad with Safari 4.0.4. I
noticed a lot of styles were not working properly:

- border-radius
- opacity
- image height & width (if only one property is declared in the css)
- etc...

I am thinking whether to make necessary css adjustments to make my web app render properly on Safari 4.0.4. While the global usage for IE6 and 7 are quite moderate. At the moment we are fine with not showing full support for these browser versions, due to their lack of css support.

Could this same consensus apply for Safari 4.0.4?

IE7's last release was on 2007 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_7). Safari 4 was on 2010 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_version_history)

If any other frontend developers faced a similar scenario. Would appreciate to hear from you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think iOS can be considered sufficiently deprecated at this point to ignore it. The iPhone 4 came with iOS 4 and the iPhone 3GS has had several updates available for it for so long that an incredibly small percentage of users would be expected to still use iOS 3.x. Further, since most mobile platforms push you to update as soon as a new version is released, there is even less of a chance anyone is using anything but the most recent 2 or 3 versions.

You can see a breakdown of iOS version usage here: http://david-smith.org/iosversionstats/

Also, your link goes to information about safari desktop versions. For iOS, go here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS_version_history

As a general rule, our company uses the 2 versions back rule, 3 for IE, unless there is a specific need for further backward compatibility per the client.

Comment: thanks! This is so helpful. I also found this link that is more into the user percentages in browsers. http://caniuse.com/usage_table.php